# What is the physical reason behind the negative differential resistance (NDR)?

Tags: condensed-matter, electrical-resistance, material-science, electronics

As you know, there is an effect called [negative differential resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_resistance) in some electric devices and materials, but I could not find any article or book or any other reference to talk about the physical reason of this effect. I mean, what happens for electrons to show such a behavior? (NDR: decrease in current by increasing voltage.)

Comment: Can be achieved by resonance effects have a look at page [190](https://books.google.de/books?id=PYxBKNl8tw8C&pg=RA4-PA219&lpg=RA4-PA219&dq=cmos+ndr&source=bl&ots=VxjE4F6Dzy&sig=0qOhdZcvmifhHW0B7_DURhLaBh4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA2o_GroPUAhWQEVAKHRsdDmkQ6AEIVjAJ#v=onepage&q=cmos%20ndr&f=false). I guess there are other ways to get an NDR as well.

Comment: It depends what kind of device you are looking at. The mechanism in a [glow tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-regulator_tube)  is different from in a [Gunn diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunn_diode) and different from the mechanism in a [tunnel diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode), just for starters.

Comment: Yeah. I think you are completely right. I look for NDR reason in nanoribbons ,specifically!!!